# Google Cloud Speech Invalid Encoding Error

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-functions, google-speech-api

When I generate a wav file and pass it to to Google Cloud Speech service as base64, I get the following error:

> Error: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: invalid encoding

I generate wav file on my angular project using recordrtc library. You can find its code below:

```
private record() {
  this.recorder = new RecordRTC.StereoAudioRecorder(this.stream, {
    mimeType: 'audio/wav',
    audioBitsPerSecond : 44100,
  });
  this.recorder.record();
}

stopRecording() {
  if (this.recorder) {
    this.recorder.stop((blob: any) => {
      if (this.startTime) {
        const wavName = encodeURIComponent('audio_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav');
        this.stopMedia();
        this._recorded.next({ blob: blob, title: wavName });
      }
    }, () => {
      this.stopMedia();
      this._recordingFailed.next("Recording failed.");
    });
  }
}

this.audioRecordingService.getRecordedBlob().subscribe((data) => {
  this.audioBlob = data.blob;
  this.audioName = data.title;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(data.blob);
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    this.audioBase64 = reader.result as string;
  }
  this.ref.detectChanges();
});
```

And then I pass the audioBase64 variable to my firebase function as parameter and call recognize function as follow;

```
export const transcriptAudio = onCall(async (data) => {
  try {
    let userId = data.auth?.token?.uid;
    if(!userId)
      throw new HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'The user is not authenticated.');

    let audioBase64 = data.data.audioBase64 as string;

    const client = new SpeechClient();
    const response = await client.recognize(
      {
        audio: {content: audioBase64 },
        config: {
          encoding: "LINEAR16",
          sampleRateHertz: 44100,
          languageCode: "en-US"}});

    const transcription = response[0].results?.map(result => result.alternatives![0].transcript).join('\n');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Transcription error: ${error}`);
  }
});
```

Somehow base64 data seems to be corrupt but I cannot see the root cause of it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the base64 file. It's content is as follows;

> data:audio/wav;base64,UklGRiTABgBXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAIAgLsAAADuAgAEABAAZGF0YQDABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

So I have decided to split it by ',' and get the second part as follows;

```
this.audioBase64= this.audioBase64.split(',')[1];
```

> UklGRiTABgBXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAIAgLsAAADuAgAEABAAZGF0YQDABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

And now it works as expected. Google Speech service expects base64 without "data:audio/wav;base64," apparently.

Now I get the following error though but the original problem is resolved;

> Must use single channel (mono) audio, but WAV header indicates 2 channels

Answer (score 0):

> Must use single channel (mono) audio, but WAV header indicates 2 channels

RecordRTC option:

```
const options = {
  ...
  numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
};
```